# Relaxation of Mind

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities

I've noticed what limits my activities in the day is a kind of mental saturation. I believe it's a kind of attention fatigue because when I walk in nature, I am more likely after to engage in projects.

**Does meditation produce the same kind of relief from attention fatigue? What kind of relaxation does meditation on the breath provide?**

Answer (score 2):

The mind generally oscillates between attachment, aversion and ignorance due to experience of pleasant, unpleasant and neutral sensations. This causes metal fatigue.

In meditation, one stops this oscillation of states by not reacting to stimuli with unwholesome states of mind. This is relaxing.

Breath meditation results in:

- concentration which suppresses certain unwholesome states
- insight which eradicates unwholesome states